# Paypal Sandbox giving 10623_AUTH while reauthorisation

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are trying to re-authorize an amount from paypal sandbox account. This feature is working fine in one of our paypal sandbox accounts.

But some of our other client sandbox accounts, are not allowing us to re-authorize any amount. It is giving us an error 10623 stating, max number of retries reached, though we have tried it for the first time only.

Are we missing something here, any insights on what needs to be taken care of here will be highly appreciated.

Regards.